# To get messages with NServiceBus do you have to have a message queue on the subscribing machine?

Tags: nservicebus

I am wondering if there is a way to setup NServiceBus so that the machine actually getting the message from a publisher does not have the *InputQueue* on it.  Also, I would like to publish to a general queue (though this can be accomplished with a web service.)

I am thinking I may use this to allow client machines to post and receive events.  But the client machines are fairly locked down.  If I need to have queues created on them I can, but it would be easier to have the queues uniquely named and in a more central location.

I am new to NServiceBus and pub/sub in general.  So if I am off base on what I want please say so.

Comment: I'm you manage to install msmq on the clients I would say that creating the queues should be less of a worry?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the perfect candidate for an alternate queuing infrastructure beyond MSMQ--such as Azure Queues or Amazon SQS.  With those types of queues you have no infrastructure to install on the client machines and everything is much more centralized.

Before you go down that road though, you'll want to get the basics of publish/subscribe under you.  Pub/sub using MSMQ and NServiceBus has a decent learning curve to it and if you aren't familiar with how things work at that level then moving to cloud queues may be even more tricky.